# Preventing HTML and SQL injection in PHP

Tags: php, html, sql-injection

Before, i used the method `htmlspecialchars($x)` to prevent the HTML tags and some SQLi on textfields. But i noticed that it not the best way to prevent it, since a single quote " ' ( ) takes some space on the database. Also, for the max-length. For example, on a text-field, i put the max-length to 1000 characters. But if the people use simbols and goes until the max length (1000 chars), the user will have some troubles, since i validate it on the server.

Example:
User types 1000 chars and he can't type anymore. About 30 chars are simbols. So, when validating, it will show more than 1000 chars and will not validate it.

Was i clear? How i can prevent these both issues?

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: [The Great Escapism (Or: What You Need To Know To Work With Text Within Text)](http://kunststube.net/escapism/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming "SQLi" is "SQL Injection," then `htmlspecialchars` will not protect you from that in queries *at all*.  `htmlspecialchars` should only be used for *display*.  You need to properly parameterize your queries so that input is appropriately sanitized for *storage*.

1. User submits form
2. You run parameterized prepared query with user input if raw input validates
3. User views page
4. You select raw input
5. Use `htmlspecialchars` on the input before you send it back to the user

Comment: And to prevent the tags on coments like, if i comment <br/> <b> or even </div>, it will destroy all my layout. That's my main problem right now. I'm converting my queries to the prepared stament way.

Comment: @JohnPetrus if your worried about some HTML being input by the user which might destroy your current styling, perform a `strpos` or `str_replace` function, which will replace an array of forbidden HTML chars

Comment: @JohnPetrus yes it will destroy it, which is why you need to use `htmlspecialchars`, but you need to use it when you are displaying it, not when you are storing it.

Comment: So, if i use it just to display, i don't need to use a string replace, to replace the symbols, right? But it's not effective against SQL Injection, right? I already didn't understand, the best way to prevent SQLi on textfields? It prepared statments, or has another solution?

Comment: @JohnPetrus you only need to protect yourself from SQL Injection at *storage time*, which is when you call `prepare`/`execute` for example; properly parameterized queries will protect you.  At *display time*, you need `htmlspecialchars`.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use htmlspecialchars() to store data, maybe like Google+. Try to view this in mobile with mobile device https://plus.google.com/app/basic/s?q=Developing+%22Web%22+Sites and scroll down. There's an entity name such &amp; and you can also use <meta charset="ISO-8859-1"> as your website's character-set to avoid an HTML tag comment such </div>, destroying your styles. Maybe your site is vulnerable from XSS for that. So, use htmlspecialchars() to store data! And be a real coder, always check a MySQL input with mysql_real_escape_string() to avoid a Sequel Injection Attack. Check these: http://evilzone.org/tutorials/sql-injection/ and www.w3schools.com/php/func_mysql_real_escape_string.asp